# parse command line arguments not reading all arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, getopt, command-line-arguments

So, I came across the [`getopt` module](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html) to parse command line args, although I can't make any sense of the docs. **For whatever reason, I cannot figure out why this isn't seeing my `--domain example.com` argument..**

```
$ ./httpdsetup.py -a -u zack --domain example.com
[('-a', ''), ('-u', '')]
```

I printed out what gets dumped into `opts` to see what it saw. The code below is just about an exact duplicate from the documentation site.

```
def main(argv):
        import getopt

        try:
                opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "h:al:ud:v", ["user=", "apache", "lighttpd", "dir=", "domain=", "vhost="])
        except getopt.GetoptError:
                print_usage()
                sys.exit(2)

        username = ''
        directory = ''
        domain = ''

        httpd = 'apache'

        print(opts)

        for opt, arg in opts:
                if opt == '-h':
                        print_usage()
                        sys.exit()
                elif opt in ('-u', '--username'):
                        username = arg
                elif opt in ('-d', '--dir'):
                        directory = arg
                elif opt in ('-v', '--domain', '--vhost'):
                        domain = arg
                elif opt in ('-a', '--apache'):
                        httpd = 'apache'
                elif opt in ('-l', '--lighttpd'):
                        httpd = 'lighttpd'
                else:
                        print_usage()
                        sys.exit()

        if httpd == 'apache':
                create_apache_vhost(domain, directory, username)
        elif httpd == 'lighttpd':
                create_lighty_vhost(domain, directory, username)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Don't use `getopt`, use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html). It is far more flexible and has a clearer interface IMO.

Comment: By chance, do you know the Debian package?

Comment: I'm getting an ImportError on importing module 'argparse', despite installing "python-argparse" package on Debian Squeeze.

Comment: `argparse` should be built in to Python 3.2.

Comment: `argparse` is not in Py <2.7 and not in Python 3.0 and 3.1. As nneonneo said it is in Python >=3.2. If you can't have it in your install, simply copy [the single file from python 3.2](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release32-maint/Lib/argparse.py) next to your script. I'd favor argparse over getopt, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `argparse`. [Python documention here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/argparse.html).
It's in Python >=2.7 and >=3.2, but not in Python 3.0 and 3.1. If it's missing in your install, just copy [the single file from here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release32-maint/Lib/argparse.py) to where your script is, or into your Python install.

Here's something close to your example with `argparse`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys



def create_apache_vhost(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def create_lighty_vhost(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def main(argv):
        import argparse

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Some server",
                                         formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

        parser.add_argument('--username', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('-u', dest='username', type=str)

        parser.add_argument('--apache', dest='httpd', action='store_const', const='apache')
        parser.add_argument('-a',       dest='httpd', action='store_const', const='apache')
        parser.add_argument('--lighthttpd', dest='httpd', action='store_const', const='lighthttpd')
        parser.add_argument('-l',           dest='httpd', action='store_const', const='lighthttpd')

        parser.add_argument('--domain', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('--vhost',  type=str)
        parser.add_argument('-v', dest='domain', type=str)

        parser.add_argument('--dir', dest='directory', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('-d', dest='directory', type=str)

        defaults = {
            'httpd': 'apache',
            }
        parser.set_defaults(**defaults)

        args = parser.parse_args(args=argv)

        print(args)

        if args.httpd == 'apache':
                create_apache_vhost(args.domain, args.directory, args.username)
        elif args.httpd == 'lighttpd':
                create_lighty_vhost(args.domain, args.directory, args.username)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks! although, I'm still rather new to Python altogether. Are the `**kwargs` (and other asterisk'd variables) arrays of pointers? o.O I have a vague understanding of C++ because I'm mostly a C# dev myself.

Comment: Side note too, I can't seem to find a working package (one that doesn't provide an ImportError) for argparse on Debian Squeeze.

Comment: Everything in Python is references, so there are no pointers. `*args` and `**kwargs` are similar to C's `varargs` in that they hold optional arguments. One `*` is positional, two `**` is named parameters.

Comment: For your argparse errors you have to provide error messages and move on to a new question or forums, I'm afraid. There's only so much space and context for comments